# Is there a way to decrease cross-posting issues?

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed, mathoverflow, cross-posting

I know there are tons of meta questions about cross-posting already. This question isn't about the cross-posting etiquette per se. It might just be a personal bias or the questions I tend to click on, but there seems to be more cross-posting to MathOverflow than usual by new users.

My thought is that this is probably due to the fact that more and more people have become aware that both of these sites exist (and the fact that I tend to only click on questions that it is reasonable to post to either site). It makes sense that new users who are aware of both sites that want an answer as fast as possible will just immediately post to both.

Is it at all reasonable to just point out that we are aware of MO existence on the help/faq page and say that if you cross-post to MO to link to it and reference it? It is mildly annoying to try to keep my eye out for this, but it is also the case that I usually catch it and post a link in the comments.

Comment: [MO is mentioned](http://math.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/on-topic), but saying something about cross-posting (when and how) might help. That said, everything is in transition these days: MO is migrating, help pages on SE are being redesigned into "help center" (and as a result, the `help` link on meta.MSE is plain **broken** right now)... it's tempting to just sit back and wait for the dust to settle.

Comment: I have added the tag ([meta-tag:cross-posting]) and ([meta-tag:mathoverflow]), since they seem relevant to your question. (At least the way I understand your question.) Feel free to retag, if you can find more suitable sets of tags or if for some reason you don't want those tags in this question.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it at all reasonable to just point out that we are aware of MO existence on the help/faq page and say that if you cross-post to MO to link to it and reference it?

It is certainly reasonable. But do keep in mind that this will be much more easily sorted out in the future:

- [MathOverflow 2.0 is a-comin'!](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9543/mathoverflow-2-0-is-a-comin)
- [What, when and will we migrate questions to MO 2.0?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4880/what-when-and-will-we-migrate-questions-to-mo-2-0)